# Grape-swagger + Unable to read api 'users' from path url (server returned undefined) + ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, ruby-grape

I am using Grape gem with rails app but I am getting below error when I call grape-swagger UI.

Error : 
Unable to read api 'users' from path https://appname.herokuapp.com/api/swagger_doc.json/users.json (server returned undefined)

Gem::
grape 0.9.0,
grape-entity 0.4.4,
grape-swagger 0.9.0, 
rails 4.1.6, 
rack-cors 0.2.9

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is confirmed bug in gem grape-swagger 0.9.0 
so they are working on it.

Still it is working with below version.

gem 'grape', '~> 0.7.0'
gem 'grape-swagger', '~> 0.7.2'

Please have a look.
https://github.com/tim-vandecasteele/grape-swagger/issues/187#issuecomment-68262716